# Extra Space on top of my Website

Tags: html, css

I have extra space on top of my website that I'm trying to get rid of. Any ideas on what I need to edit in CSS to get rid of this? I'm using the Overflow theme from html5up. I got rid of the gallery section of the page, so maybe this is why I have the extra space? This is my first payed project, so I'm very anxious to get this job correct!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
/* Basic */

     body {
      background-color: #183026;
      background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
      background-size: auto, cover;
      background-position: top left, center 0;
      background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-size: 18pt;
      line-height: 1.75em;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      color: #3a3939;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(58, 57, 57, 0.25);
      -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px;
     }

      body.is-scroll {
       background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
       background-size: auto, 100% auto;
      }

      body.is-loading * {
       -moz-transition: none !important;
       -webkit-transition: none !important;
       -ms-transition: none !important;
       transition: none !important;
       -moz-animation: none !important;
       -webkit-animation: none !important;
       -ms-animation: none !important;
       animation: none !important;
      }

     input, textarea, select {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-size: 18pt;
      line-height: 1.75em;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      color: #3a3939;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(58, 57, 57, 0.25);
      -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px;
     }

     h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      line-height: 1.75em;
     }

     h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
     }

     h2 {
      font-size: 1.25em;
      letter-spacing: 8px;
     }

     h3 {
      font-size: 1em;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
     }

     strong, b {
      font-weight: 400;
     }

     em, i {
      font-style: italic;
     }

     a {
      -moz-transition: border-color 0.35s ease-in-out, color 0.35s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: border-color 0.35s ease-in-out, color 0.35s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: border-color 0.35s ease-in-out, color 0.35s ease-in-out;
      transition: border-color 0.35s ease-in-out, color 0.35s ease-in-out;
      color: #35b88f;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(53, 184, 143, 0.25);
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(53, 184, 143, 0.5);
     }

      a:hover {
       border-bottom-color: rgba(53, 184, 143, 0);
      }

     sub {
      position: relative;
      top: 0.5em;
      font-size: 0.8em;
     }

     sup {
      position: relative;
      top: -0.5em;
      font-size: 0.8em;
     }

     hr {
      border: 0;
      border-top: solid 1px #dad9d9;
      margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
     }

     blockquote {
      border-left: solid 0.5em #eae9e9;
      padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
      font-style: italic;
     }

     p, ul, ol, dl, table {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
     }

     header {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
     }

      header p {
       display: block;
       margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
       padding: 0 0 1.5em 0;
      }

     footer {
      margin-top: 1em;
     }

     br.clear {
      clear: both;
     }

    /* Sections/Article */

     section, article {
      margin-bottom: 3em;
     }

     section > :last-child,
     article > :last-child,
     section:last-child,
     article:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
     }

     .row > section, .row > article {
      margin-bottom: 0;
     }

    /* Image */

     .image {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 0;
     }

      .image img {
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
      }

      .image.featured {
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      }

      .image.fit {
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
      }

      .image.left {
       float: left;
       margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
      }

      .image.centered {
       display: block;
       margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      }

       .image.centered img {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: auto;
       }

    /* List */

     ul.default {
      list-style: disc;
      padding-left: 1em;
     }

      ul.default li {
       padding-left: 1.5em;
       margin-top: 1.5em;
      }

       ul.default li:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
       }

     ul.icons {
      cursor: default;
     }

      ul.icons li {
       display: inline-block;
      }

      ul.icons a {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 2.5em;
       height: 2.5em;
       line-height: 2.5em;
       text-align: center;
       border: 0;
      }

     ul.menu {
      cursor: default;
     }

      ul.menu li {
       display: inline-block;
       line-height: 1em;
       border-left: solid 1px #dad9d9;
       padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
       margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
      }

       ul.menu li:first-child {
        border-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
       }

     ul.actions {
      cursor: default;
     }

      ul.actions li {
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
      }

       ul.actions li:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
       }

     ol.default {
      list-style: decimal;
      padding-left: 1.25em;
     }

      ol.default li {
       padding-left: 1.25em;
       margin-top: 1.5em;
      }

   

    /* Banner */

     #banner {
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
      text-align: center;
      background: #35b88f url("images/banner.svg") bottom center no-repeat;
      padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-size: 125% auto;
     }

      #banner .button {
       color: #35b882;
       text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(53, 184, 130, 0.25);
      }

      #banner header {
       margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      }

       #banner header h2 {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1.75em;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
       }

      #banner p {
       margin: 0;
      }

      #banner footer {
       margin: 2em 0 0 0;
      }

      #banner a {
       color: inherit;
       border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      }

       #banner a:hover {
        border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
       }

    /* Footer */

     #footer {
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
      text-align: center;
      margin: 4.5em 0 0 0;
     }

      #footer:after {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       top: -4.5em;
       left: 50%;
       height: 4.5em;
       border-left: solid 1px #fff;
      }

      #footer a {
       color: #fff;
       text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
       border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      }

       #footer a:hover {
        color: #35b88f;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(69, 200, 159, 0.25);
        border-bottom-color: rgba(53, 184, 143, 0.5);
       }

      #footer .icons {
       padding: 0.75em 2em 0.75em 2em;
       border-radius: 3em;
       border: solid 1px #fff;
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0 0 3em 0;
      }

      #footer .copyright {
       margin: 0 0 9em 0;
       font-size: 0.8em;
      }

    
      /* Header */

       #header {
        padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
       }

        #header header {
         padding-left: 2em;
         padding-right: 2em;
        }

         #header header h1 {
          font-size: 1.75em;
          letter-spacing: 6px;
         }

        #header footer {
         bottom: 4.5em;
         padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
        }

         #header footer:after {
          bottom: -4.5em;
          left: 50%;
          height: 4.5em;
         }

         #header footer:before {
          width: 45px;
          height: 33px;
          bottom: -2.25em;
          margin-left: -22.5px;
          margin-bottom: -16.5px;
          background-size: 45px 33px;
         }

      /* Banner */

       #banner {
        padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
        background-size: auto 150%;
       }

        #banner header {
         margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        }

         #banner header h2 {
          font-size: 1.5em;
          letter-spacing: 6px;
         }

      /* Footer */

       #footer .icons {
        padding: 0.5em 1.25em 0.5em 1.25em;
       }

       #footer .copyright {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0 0 4em 0;
       }

      /* Poptrox */

       .poptrox-popup .nav-next,
       .poptrox-popup .nav-previous {
        opacity: 1.0;
       }

        .poptrox-popup .nav-next:before,
        .poptrox-popup .nav-previous:before {
         display: none;
        }

       .poptrox-popup .closer {
        opacity: 0.5;
       }

     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
   Overflow by HTML5 UP
   html5up.net | @ajlkn
   Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
   -->
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Sunbelt Group</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
      <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" />
      <![endif]-->
      <!-- webform.pw -->
      <!-- webform.pw 
         <script> web_form_id = "a9771519-bb14-453d-b997-26d751bc3e79" </script>
         <script type="text/javascript"
             src="https://webform.pw/client/formclient.nocache.js">
         </script>
         -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Header -->
      <section id="header">
         <header>
            <h1><img src="images/sunbeltgrouplogo.png" alt="" /></h1>
         </header>
         <footer>
            <a href="#banner" class="button style2 scrolly-middle">About Us</a>
         </footer>
      </section>
      <!-- Banner -->
      <section id="banner">
         <header>
            <h2>Who We Are</h2>
         </header>
         <p>The Sunbelt Group is an online business marketer.  <br />Our mission:  maximize your exposure on the Internet. <br />We work to put your business in front of the greatest number of prospects as possible.</p>
         <footer>
            <a href="#first" class="button style2 scrolly">Our Services</a>
         </footer>
      </section>
      <!-- Feature 1 -->
      <article id="first" class="container box style1 right">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/strategyimg.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <div class="inner">
            <header>
               <h2>Strategic Advertising</h2>
            </header>
            <!-- Feature 1 -->
            <p>Tortor faucibus ullamcorper nec tempus purus sed penatibus. Lacinia pellentesque eleifend vitae est elit tristique velit tempus etiam.</p>
         </div>
      </article>
      <!-- Feature 2 -->
      <article class="container box style1 left">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/targetmarketimg3bw.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <div class="inner">
            <header>
               <h2>Targeted Exposure</h2>
            </header>
            <p>Rhoncus mattis egestas sed fusce sodales rutrum et etiam ullamcorper. Etiam egestas scelerisque ac duis magna lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
         </div>
      </article>
      <!-- Feature 3 -->
      <article id="first" class="container box style1 right">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/dedicatedsupport.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <div class="inner">
            <header>
               <h2>Dedicated Support</h2>
            </header>
            <p>Tortor faucibus ullamcorper nec tempus purus sed penatibus. Lacinia pellentesque eleifend vitae est elit tristique velit tempus etiam.</p>
         </div>
      </article>
      <!-- Contact -->
      <article class="container box style3">
         <header>
            <h2>Connect With Us</h2>
            <p>tom.miyata@outlook.com <br />
               (312) 391-3910
            </p>
         </header>
         <form method="post" action="https://formspree.io/tgkwebservices@gmail.com">
            <div class="row 50%">
               <div class="6u 12u$(mobile)"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
               <div class="6u$ 12u$(mobile)"><input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
               <div class="12u$">
                  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="12u$">
                  <ul class="actions">
                     <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </article>
      <!-- Generic -->
      <!--
         <article class="container box style3">
             <header>
                 <h2>Generic Box</h2>
                 <p>Just a generic box. Nothing to see here.</p>
             </header>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Paragraph</h3>
                     <p>This is a subtitle</p>
                 </header>
                 <p>Phasellus nisl nisl, varius id <sup>porttitor sed pellentesque</sup> ac orci. Pellentesque
                 habitant <strong>strong</strong> tristique <b>bold</b> et netus <i>italic</i> malesuada <em>emphasized</em> ac turpis egestas. Morbi
                 leo suscipit ut. Praesent <sub>id turpis vitae</sub> turpis pretium ultricies. Vestibulum sit
                 amet risus elit.</p>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Blockquote</h3>
                 </header>
                 <blockquote>Fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis tincidunt felis sagittis eget.
                 tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</blockquote>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Divider</h3>
                 </header>
                 <p>Donec consectetur <a href="#">vestibulum dolor et pulvinar</a>. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra
                 ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel. Praesent nec orci
                 facilisis leo magna. Cras sit amet urna eros, id egestas urna. Quisque aliquam
                 tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
                 posuere cubilia.</p>
                 <hr />
                 <p>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra
                 ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel. Praesent nec orci
                 facilisis leo magna. Cras sit amet urna eros, id egestas urna. Quisque aliquam
                 tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
                 posuere cubilia.</p>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Unordered List</h3>
                 </header>
                 <ul class="default">
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                 </ul>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Ordered List</h3>
                 </header>
                 <ol class="default">
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                     <li>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel.</li>
                 </ol>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Table</h3>
                 </header>
                 <div class="table-wrapper">
                     <table class="default">
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>ID</th>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                                 <th>Description</th>
                                 <th>Price</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>45815</td>
                                 <td>Something</td>
                                 <td>Ut porttitor sagittis lorem quis nisi ornare.</td>
                                 <td>29.99</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>24524</td>
                                 <td>Nothing</td>
                                 <td>Ut porttitor sagittis lorem quis nisi ornare.</td>
                                 <td>19.99</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>45815</td>
                                 <td>Something</td>
                                 <td>Ut porttitor sagittis lorem quis nisi ornare.</td>
                                 <td>29.99</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>24524</td>
                                 <td>Nothing</td>
                                 <td>Ut porttitor sagittis lorem quis nisi ornare.</td>
                                 <td>19.99</td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                         <tfoot>
                             <tr>
                                 <td colspan="3"></td>
                                 <td>100.00</td>
                             </tr>
                         </tfoot>
                     </table>
                 </div>
             </section>
             <section>
                 <header>
                     <h3>Form</h3>
                 </header>
                 <form method="post" action="#">
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="6u">
                             <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="John Doe" />
                         </div>
                         <div class="6u">
                             <input class="text" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@domain.tld" />
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="12u">
                             <select name="department" id="department">
                                 <option value="">Choose a department</option>
                                 <option value="1">Manufacturing</option>
                                 <option value="2">Administration</option>
                                 <option value="3">Support</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="12u">
                             <input class="text" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Enter your subject" />
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="12u">
                             <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="12u">
                             <ul class="actions">
                                 <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
                                 <li><input type="reset" class="style3" value="Clear Form" /></li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </section>
         </article>
         -->
      <section id="footer">
         <ul class="icons">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-google-plus"><span class="label">Google+</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-pinterest"><span class="label">Pinterest</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-linkedin"><span class="label">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <div class="copyright">
            <ul class="menu">
               <li>&copy; The Sunbelt Group. All rights reserved.</li>
               <li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
      <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to read your code like this (use a snippet), but you checked whether the padding for `#header` is causing the gap?

Comment: Thank you so so much for the reply. I tried messing with the padding but doesn't seem to do anything. Sorry, this is my first time posting a question. I had to reduce my code to fit in the post because I was exceeding the 30000 word limit.

Answer (score 1):

From your live version, remove the padding from `<section id="header"></section>` and make

```
#header {
  padding: 3em 0 9em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Hmmm...This does not seem to work

Comment: Right now, you have `style="padding: 192px 0px;"` added to your section header. Remove that, and change the padding as I suggested in your CSS. Believe me :)

Comment: That's strange....when I view my code in dream weaver there is not style added to the section header, but when I view it in firefox firebug I can the style code in the html. This is a template I used from html5up. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Well, probably something's going on in your JS.. Hard to tell, sorry. This is the reason I am not a fan of templates.

Comment: That's right. If you view the source it just says <section id="header"> but when you inspect the element, it has an extra style attribute with the padding. Apparently this is set in the JavaScript file assets/js/main.js, for whatever reason.

Comment: Ah! I think I figured it out. I went to the JS file and searched "192". When I did this it took me to the line of code that was doing this. I then messed with the "192" number and decreased it, and it worked! Thank you guys for your input! especially Thomas van Broekhoven. Thank you!

Comment: Having trouble making everything align for different screens....this is so frustrating!

Comment: I think the best thing is to remove the `192` you found and then, give it the padding I suggested. You tried that?

Comment: Works now!!!! I removed the code completely in the JS file. Thank you so so much Thomas van Broekhoven!!! You're awesome!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Hope you learned how to tackle things like this now :)

Comment: I definitely did!!